# Crossing vs. not crossing - or - The two sides of a curve

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Intuitively, the difference between *crossing* and *non-crossing* (= touching but not crossing) curves at a point in a 2-dimensional space is:

- non-crossing curves remain on one "side" with respect to the other curve
- crossing curves change "sides" (from one to the other)

When something like [Jordan's curve theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) applies there is a *global* and definite notion of "sides": two path-connected regions into which the space is split by a *closed* curve. If only one of the two curves is closed **and** splits the space in two regions (the "inside" and the "outside") there will be a clear-cut distinction between "crossing" and "non-crossing".

But more often than not Jordan's curve theorem is *not* applicable, e.g. on the torus. Nevertheless, there seems to be a *local* notion of "sides", especially for curves that are *not* closed.

A naive approach: In every 2-dimensional space there seem to be loops small enough to split the space in two. (The non-splitting loops have to be large enough.) Cutting out a small enough piece of *any* curve one can join its two ends to form such a small enough loop, and this loop then locally defines an "inside" and an "outside".

> (How) can this approach be made rigorous to distinguish between crossing and non-crossing curves?

And/or what are the appropriate keywords to look up in textbooks?

**Edit**: Sorry for confusions I might have created by using the wrong term. I have mistaken "osculating" to mean "touching but not crossing". My question is about this (second) notion which presumably makes only sense in dimension 2.

Comment: I am not an expert on kissing. But $y=x^3$ and $y=0$ kiss and cross at $0$. If $y=0$ is not curvy enough, we can use $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$.

Comment: I think you can't make it rigorous look at the graphs of $f_1(x)=0$ $f_2=\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ and $\sin^2(\frac{1}{x}) \exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best first attempt is:

Suppose two curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ in a topological space $X$ intersect at $x \in X$. Then this intersection is a "kissing" intersection if for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there are path homotopies of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ to paths which do not intersect in $U$, and these path homotopies are constant outside of $U$

This definition seems like it needs a little massaging to make it totally rigorous, but maybe it's on the right track?

Comment: To be honest: I do not understand your attempt (but this is probably more of my problem than of yours). How do the homotopies you mention prevent $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ from crossing? Especially by being constant outside of $U$? And what exactly means "constant outside of $U$"? Could you - eventually - draw a sketch?

Comment: Here's what I mean intuitively: Suppose we have two paths that kiss. Then if I take one of the paths and move it a very small amount, the paths won't intersect anymore (this is what I mean by a "homotopy"). But, if the paths have a true crossing, then you won't be able to remove the intersection by just moving the paths slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Curves kiss at a point iff their tangent spaces at that point are equal under their canonical embedding into the space. I've had to formulate this too, recently, and that's the definition I've settled on.