# Homotopy on loops that intersect exactly once

Tags: algebraic-topology

Two simple loops $\alpha, \beta$ on a surface intersect each other exactly once, and $\alpha$ is not null-homotopic. Does it follow that $\beta$ is also not null-homotopic?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't impose further conditions then the answer is no, as shown in WoolierThanThou's answer. You can even find a counterexample on a compact surface (e.g. a torus, where one of the loops is a generator of $\pi_1$ and the other is a small loop that's tangent to the first loop).

However, the answer changes if you require the loops to intersect *transversely*. If your surface and your curves are smooth, then the two curves are said to intersect transversely if the tangent vectors of the curves at the intersection are not parallel. If your surface is closed (and connected), then Poincaré duality tells you that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are dual to cohomology classes $x,y \in H^1(\Sigma; \mathbb{F}_2)$. Moreover, since the intersection is transverse the cup product $x \smile y \in H^2(\Sigma; \mathbb{F}_2) = \mathbb{F}_2$ is equal to the reduction mod $2$ of the number of intersections of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. There is only one intersection, so the cup product is nontrivial. Therefore the cohomology class $y$ cannot be $0$, and therefore the homology class $[\beta]$ cannot be zero, so finally the loop $\beta$ cannot be nullhomotopic.

(Note that I haven't even used the hypothesis that $\alpha$ is not nullhomotopic: on a closed surface, a nullhomotopic curve always intersects transversely another curve an even number of times.)

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the surface $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{0\}$ (with chart given by the complex exponential function if you'd like) and consider $\alpha(t)=e^{it}$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\beta(t)=2+e^{-it}$ for $t\in[\pi,3\pi]$. Then, the two curves exactly intersect at $1$, but $\alpha$ is not null-homotopic (it is a generator of the fundamental group under the homotopy equivalence between  $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ and $S^1$), and $\beta$ clearly is - you can just use the straight-line homotopy.

Comment: This is not what people typically mean when they say curves intersect, yet I'm struggling to formalize it properly. Do you have a similar example where curve passes 'to the other side' of the other? In your example there is inside and outside of those circles for example.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you're asking.These two circles turn away from each other. I mean... you could also consider $\beta(t)= \frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}e^{it}$ if you want one inside the other?

Comment: They are just tangent and it seems to me it makes a difference here. When I look at this it looks to me like intersection with even multiplicity. If you perturb one of the curves by arbitrarily small difference number of intersections goes either to 0 or 2. (I really don't like this formally because it refers to metric structure). Perhaps you could demand that intersection is locally homeomorphic to X-like intersection and not )(-like intersection.

Comment: Well, the shape X and the shape )( are homeomorphic, so I don't seen what difference that would make? The Jordan curve theorem implies that two simple loops in $\mathbb{R}^2$ must intersect at an even number of times.

Comment: Oh, you mean that the curves might cross through each other? Again, in this case, they must intersect twice, and you can take the example $\beta(t)=\frac{3}{2}+e^{-it}$.

Comment: About 'X' \sim ')(' : if you want to map line to line respectively without messing up the space between the lines it's not possible isn't it?
About 'cross through each other': this is precisely my point. As you said 'they must intersect twice' and I agree with this intuition that otherwise $\beta$ is not nullhomotopic can you formalize this? Does this warrant making another question?
I think I found a question which formalizes my concern:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328563/crossing-vs-not-crossing-or-the-two-sides-of-a-curve

Comment: You can bend the arms of $X$ to make two circles touching. And I'm saying that *any* two simple loops in $\mathbb{R}^2$ must intersect an even number of times (counting tangent points with multiplicity two, since otherwise, this is parametrisation dependent), and this follows directly from the Jordan Curve Theorem.